# "Umstand" und "Umstandskleid" - Bedeutung und Herkunft

Tags: meaning, etymology, synonym

Ich habe vor kurzem die Bedeutung des Wortes "Umstand" gesucht. Allgemein bedeutet es:

> Situation und besondere Verhältnisse, die für ein Geschehen bemerkenswert sind <sup>[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Umstand)</sup>

Später, als ich das Wort in Google-Bilder gesucht hatte, habe ich viele Fotos von "Umstandskleider" gefunden. Ich habe auch bemerkt, dass das Wort "Umstand" manchmal als Synonym des Wortes "Umstandskleid" benutzt wird (z.B. [in diesem Online-Shop](https://www.glueckskind-online.de/umstand/)). Doch habe ich keine Informationen über dieses Synonym in Wörterbüchern gefunden.
Darum habe ich zwei Fragen:

1. Kann man wirklich "Umstand" als Synonym zu "Umstandskleid" benutzen? Ist das ein neues Synonym, das noch nicht in Wörterbüchern aufgenommen wurde?
2. Was ist die Herkunft des Wortes "Umstandskleid"? Kann man sagen, dass die schwangere Frau einen "besonderen Umstand" hat bzw. in einem ist? Dann könne das "das Kleid des besonderen Umstands" meinen.
   Doch wieso gibt es keine weiteren Wörter, die diese Bedeutung nutzen? Auf Englisch heißt es "maternity dress". Aber englisches "maternity" wird allgemein als "Mutterschaft" übersetzt, auch in Wortkombinationen (z.B. "maternity allowance" -> "Mutterschaftsbeihilfe", "maternity leave" -> "Mutterschaftsurlaub"). "Umstandskleid" sieht wie eine Ausnahme aus.

Comment: "Ich habe auch bemerkt, dass das Wort 'Umstand' manchmal als Synonym des Wortes 'Umstandskleid' benutzt wird (z.B. in diesem Online-Shop https://www.glueckskind-online.de/umstand/ )." - sehe ich nicht so. Das Wort "Baby" auf derselben Website ist schließlich auch kein Synonym für "Babykleidung". Vielmehr stellen "Umstand" und "Baby" prägnante Stichworte dar, welche die Produktkategorie identifizieren, dabei aber nicht notwendigerweise selber die Produktbezeichnung darstellen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das klingt logisch. Danke für die Erklärung.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"In anderen Umständen sein" ist ein Euphemismus für "schwanger sein", entstanden wohl zu Zeiten, als es "sich nicht gehört hat" über "sowas" zu reden. Der Ausdruck wird durchaus heute noch genutzt, ist aber veraltend. Gehalten hat er sich noch in den Begriffen wie "Umstandsmode", "Umstandskleid", "Umstandshose", sogar "Umstandsbadeanzug" (Diese Begriffe tauchen durchaus auch im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Umstandsmode) auf) - Außerhalb der textilen Begrifflichkeit habe ich den Begriff schon lange nicht mehr gehört. Deine Vermutung (2) trifft also ziemlich genau zu.

*Umstand* alleine kommt allerdings nicht als Synonym für "schwanger" oder "Schwangerschaftskleidung" in Frage.

Warum hier nicht von *Mutterschaft* geredet wird? Eine schwangere Frau ist nicht notwendigerweise schon Mutter, sondern wird es erst noch. Der frühere Begriff *Mutterschaftsurlaub*, den es z.B. im Arbeitsrecht gab, definierte sich als "Urlaub **nach** der Geburt eines Kindes"

Answer (score 9):

Es gibt den Ausdruck

> Sie ist in anderen Umständen

womit gesagt werden soll: "Sie ist schwanger"; jedoch hat man in früheren Zeiten solche direkten Formulierungen gescheut und die Sache lieber "umständlich" umschrieben.

Das *Umstandskleid* kommt wohl von diesen *anderen Umständen*, vermute ich.

*Umstand* als Synonym für *Umstandskleid* ist mir noch nie begegnet. In deinem Beispiel scheint es ja auch nur in einer Dateistrukturkette für eine Web-Adresse aufzutauchen. Dort kann es schon mal vorkommen, dass der Programmierer, um die Sache kurz zu halten, aus *Umstandsmode* (ein Wort, das es tatsächlich gibt) kurz einfach *Umstand* macht.

Das Wort *Umstandsmode* ist gleichzeitig die Antwort auf deine dritte Frage: Ja, es gibt andere Zusammensetzungen mit *Umstand-*. Schnelles Anwerfen einer Suchmaschine deiner Wahl hätte dir auch gezeigt:

> Umstandskleidung
>
> Umstandsbademode
>
> Umstandsschlafanzug

Comment: Über der letzte Absatz: das ist richtig - vielleicht habe ich zu viel das englische _maternity_ und seine Übersetzungen analysiert. Ich sollte besonders das _Im Alphabet danach_ Abschnitt in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Umstandskleid) anschauen.